# Set URI query to a procedure so that it may change with each request

Tags: ruby, http

I have a poller setup to query a URL every second. However, I'm trying to change the query of a request that I'm making since the query contains an expiring security token and needs to be resigned with a new time.

Something like this would work for me:

```
class Poller 
  def initialize(uri, query)
    @uri = URI.parse("https://www.google.com")
    @uri.query = query
  end

  # This is in a class running in a loop running once a second
  def run
    Net::HTTPS.start(@uri.host, @uri.port) do |http|
      # My changing request.
      http.request(@query) do |response|
        # Do stuff with response
      end
    end
  end
end

Poller.new('https://www.google.com', query: my_proc_method) do |fh|
  file = File.new(fh)
  hash = Hash.from_xml(file)
end
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How do I create the query dynamically, with the time? The above code is pseudo.